«Остальные остатки», «запасенные припасы» — это не тавтологии?

Тавтология — лингв. повторение однокоренных слов или морфем в пределах одного текста, одной фразы.

Запасенные припасы — не тавтология по данному определению, так как корни разные.
Остальные остатки — не тавтология по данному определению, так как корни разные.

Вопрос резонный.

Нет, это не тавтологии, а плеоназмы. Плеона́зм — оборот речи, в котором происходит дублирование некоторого элемента смысла

"Вася заготовил заготовки (дверей для станка)." А в чем тут дублирование смысла? Заготовки для дверей, но заготовил для станка - совсем разные смыслы готовки. Так же и в любых плеоназмах - смысл зависит от контекста, возможны варианты (по определению), когда плеоназмы не плеоназмы. Запасенные припасы - да чаще всего будет плеоназм, но не всегда.

Тавтология однозначно, здесь звуковой повтор: оСТАльные  оСТАтки, заПАСенные приПАСы.  Уши режет, причем определяется сразу.
Но и плеоназм (избыточный смысл) тоже присутствует, в том числе для запасенные припасы.
Пример: Вода еще оставалась, но запасенные припасы еды кончились. Смысл не дублируется, но так не говорят.
